# Excel Formula Referencing Itself Doesn't Update Automatically

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

So I have a cell which I am using the following formula for (the formula is in cell B3):

```
=IF(F3="Open",IF(B3>0,B3,TODAY()),IF(B3>0, B3, ""))
```

The formula works properly, but it only updates if I click in the cell and hit enter.  I have formulas turned on to calculate automatically so that is not the issue.  Even if I hit "Calculate Sheet", it doesn't update.

My end goal here is to change the value of B3 to today's date when the value of cell F3 is "Open", unless the value of B3 is already a date, then changing to "Open" should result in no change to cell B3. When the value of F3 is not "Open", B3 should also keep its current value.

I unfortunately can't use macros in this sheet.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening here. I put several of those formulae in a worksheet and all of them update whenever B3 changes goes from above zero to below and vice versa while F3 is "Open". By the way, your formula could be simplified to: `=IF(B3>0,B3,IF(F3="Open",TODAY(),""))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that you have Iteration turned on in calculation Options (this is required to solve circular references).
 and I think your formula should be

```
=IF(F3="Open",IF(AND(B3<>"",B3>0),B3,TODAY()),IF(B3>0, B3, ""))
```

Comment: Adding the AND statement to both nested IFs solved my problem.  Thank you!